# JQuery fileupload and ie9

Tags: jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-9

for some reason ie9 won't upload anything to the server and it won't fire the fail nor the success or done callbacks. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<label class="profile-image-container btn-act-green" id="fileupload" data-url="{% url 'festival_registration_file_upload' uidb36 token %}" for="id_image_upload">
    <input type="file" name="image_upload[image_upload]" id="id_image_upload" accept="image/*" multiple>
</label>
```

js:

```
    $(this).find('input[type="file"]').fileupload({
        url: $el_root.attr('data-url'),
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        autoUpload: true,
        dataType: 'json',

        add: function(e, data) {
            data.submit();
        },
        fail: function(e,data) {
            alert('fail')
        },
        success: function(e, data) {
            alert('success')
        },
        done: function(e, data) {
            $progress_bar.css('width', '0%');
            $el_root.addClass('image-uplaoded').removeClass("error");
            $('#id_profile_image').val(data.result.fields.image_upload);

            $image_tag.attr({
                'src': data.result.image_url,
                'width': image_width,
                'height': image_height,
                'position': 'absolute'
            }).css({
                'top': 0,
                'left': 0
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('.progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    })
```

Does anyone see the problem?

I'm testing on a virtual machine: win7 and ie9

Comment: I know files load because if I put alert ('add') in the add function it shows me the alert box. No errors in the console

Comment: Hi Jonas, were you able to resolve this? You posted over a year ago. If so, can you remember what you did?

Comment: I'm sorry, no, too much time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 support appears to be sketchy for the plugin.

See [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2109) and [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2655). See also [browser support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support).

**Edit**: In the second link above, the plugin creator provides an explanation on how to fix it. Unfortunately, I do not have any experience in this, so I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Both links are dead ... ;-(